# nodejs jsdom disable inline script

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

Is there a way to disable inline scripts in jsdom? I've found how to disable external scripts but it don't want inline scripts to execute when i'm creating a dom.

Thanks,

Comment: I have the same problem. I'd like to import an HMTL file, parse it using jsdom to use its DOM API on the elements.

Comment: I actually got an awnser from jsdom via github.
https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/1512